# friendly_id and acts_as_paranoid creating duplicate slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, acts-as-paranoid

I'm current using acts_as_paranoid and friendly_id (5.0.1) on a model and when I destroy a model and try to create a new one that will generate the same slug I get:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_papers_on_slug"
```

I need to somehow get the code that checks if a slug already exists check within the scope of all of the objects not just the non-deleted ones.

How can I get friendly_id to use `with_deleted` when checking if a slug already exists. I should note that I am also using slug history which may be complicating things further.

Upon digging deeper I realized that since I am using history the slug is being fully deleted while the object is just being soft deleted:

```
DELETE FROM "friendly_id_slugs" WHERE "friendly_id_slugs"."id" = $1  [["id", 9423]]
```

So, I just need to figure out how to prevent this and I should be okay since it looks like the friendly_id code itself is already using `unscoped` when trying to find a valid slug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following to the model allowed me to overrride the dependent destroy on the slugs

```
def has_many_dependent_for_slugs; end
```

The solution comes from a comment on this [github issue](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/pull/268).

Answer (score 2):

Friendly_id has a module called [`scoped`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/scoped.rb) which allows you to generate unique slugs within a scope. So, probably

```
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, :use => :scoped, :scope => :unscoped
end
```

will resolve the problem.

Comment: This causes the following error: `undefined method unscoped for Paper`

Comment: Hmm, can you try creating a wrapper scope calling `unscoped` inside of it?

Comment: The problem seems to be that friendly_id scopes expect to be scoping on other properties of the object and not necessarily setting the scope of the search, so when I created a new method it then complains that the unscoped column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue too and I figured two different ways to address it.

**Solution 1:**

Use `dependent: false`.

`friendly_id :title, dependent: false`

**Solution: 2**

Overcoming this problem without overriding the dependent `destroy` for anyone that wants to avoid that.

The friendly_id gem uses a [method](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/81442a69df30a604e63fbbd789ba22464de5c758/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L361) called `scope_for_slug_generator` to set the model scope. That means we could override this method by adding the following to `app/config/initializers/friendly_id.rb`.

```
module FriendlyId
  def scope_for_slug_generator
    scope = if self.class.base_class.include?(Paranoia)
      self.class.base_class.unscoped.with_deleted
    else
      self.class.base_class.unscoped
    end
 
    scope = self.class.base_class.unscoped
    scope = scope.friendly unless scope.respond_to?(:exists_by_friendly_id?)
    primary_key_name = self.class.primary_key
      
    scope.where(self.class.base_class.arel_table[primary_key_name].not_eq(send(primary_key_name)))
  end
end
```